# Trying to make use of Jcrop and serverside image resizing with scala Scrimage lib

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, jcrop, scrimage

I'm trying to combine **jcrop** and **scrimage** but I'm having trouble in understanding
the documentation of scrimage. 
The user uploads an image. When the upload is done the user is able choose a fixed
area to crop with Jcrop:

**upload.js**

```
      $(function () {
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',                    
                progress: function (e, data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                    $("#progress").find(".progress-bar").css(
                        "width",
                        progress + "%"
                    );
                },
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $("#cropArea").empty();
                    var cropWidth = 210;
                    var cropHeight = 144;
                    if(data.result.status == 200) {
                        var myImage = $("<img></img>", {
                            src: data.result.link
                        }).appendTo('#cropArea');
                        var c = myImage.Jcrop({
                            allowResize: false,
                            allowSelect: false,
                            setSelect:[0,0,cropWidth,cropHeight],
                            onSelect: showCoords
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

**Example:**

[image: Cropped Area]

When the user is satisfied the coordinates will be posted to the server and there is where the magic should happen.

**Controller:**

```
def uploadFile = Action(multipartFormDataAsBytes) { request =>
    val result = request.body.files.map {
      case FilePart(key, filename, contentType, bytes) => {
        val coords = request.body.dataParts.get("coords")
        val bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
        Image(bais).resize(magic stuff with coords)

        Ok("works")
      }
    }
    result(0)
  }
```

If i read the [docs](https://github.com/sksamuel/scrimage) for **scrimage** and **resize**:

> Resizes the canvas to the given dimensions. This does not scale the
>   image but simply changes the dimensions of the canvas on which the
>   image is sitting. Specifying a larger size will pad the image with a
>   background color and specifying a smaller size will crop the image.
>   This is the operation most people want when they think of crop.

But when trying to implement resize with an inputstream `Image(is).resize()` I'm not sure I how should do this. Resize takes a scaleFactor, position and color... I guess I should
populate the position with the coords I get from jcrop??, and what do I do with the scaleFactor? Anybody got a good example of how to do this this?

Thank you for two great libs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subimage is what you want. That lets you specify coordinates rather than offsets.

So simply,

```
val image = // original
val resized = image.subimage(x,y,w,h) // you'll get these from jcrop somehow
```

Comment: Amazing! But upgrade your answer with image.subimage(x1,y1,w,h) and I will mark it as correct!